# How do I create an Alexa skill that gives the answers from my own database using node.js 8.10

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

i am a beginner and trying to develop an Alexa skill which can store data to be retrieved later for my college project.

Comment: Good to know, I hope you have fun with that

Comment: Please be more specific about what issue you're having (preferably providing examples of what code you've tried so far). Stack Overflow is here to help you fix your code - we can't write it for you!

Comment: [How to ask on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I found a way to solve this problem. I would try to be more clear in the next question. Thank you for your valuable responses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

But before it gets closed here is a guide I found to get you going:

https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-an-alexa-skill-with-node-js-and-dynamodb-3c9d5e9661

When you have a question, with worked examples, and a specific question, come back and ask another question :).

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for helping, the article is really helpful.                                                    The question was not so clear to understand that's my fault, I'm a student and new to this field. Just started learning programming.

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere.